# What does this php/mysql code mean. concat, LIKE and concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, concatenation

```
$num = "1";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM perp_users WHERE concat(activate) LIKE '$num'");
```

just need a simple explanation

I know its retrieving a result from sql selecting from a table then i get confused afterwards.

Please explain thanks!

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvotehtml (Lack of research - what in the manual is unclear? Do you know the language?)

Comment: concat means to join 2 or more items together. I am not sure what activate is.

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: "No input file specified." sure is a valid reason to downvote a question.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet is pulling all columns from the `perp_users` table, where the column `activate` is similar to '1';

It can probably be rewritten as:

```
SELECT *
FROM perp_users
WHERE activate = '$num';
```

[`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) joins columns together into one result, but since you're only using it on one column, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! This really has helped me!

Answer (score 0):

In this usage, `concat(activate)` is the same as `activate`.  The [`concat()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) concatenates strings, and it would normally be used with multiple arguments, like

```
...  concat (str1, str2, str3, str4, str5) ...
```

The [`LIKE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) does a string comparison which is more relaxed than a straight `=`; it also allows simple wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

[The LIKE operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) It's most commonly used in conjunction with wildcards.

`concat` is concatenation, or joining the results from two columns. In this case, it's not doing anything since it's sent only one column. Usually it's sent multiple arguments to contactenate together, ie. `concat (col1, col2, col3)`.

The full query is selecting all columns from the table `perp_users` where `activate` matches the pattern `$num`. In this case, both `concat()` and `LIKE` are unnecessary.